# connecting to client system using ip address

Tags: java

I am doing a chating  program in java.How can i Connect the server to a particular client system by entering its IP address?

Comment: Usually it's the client that connects to a server using the server's IP address.

Answer (score 4):

Without being rude, your question seems to be one of "How do I win the F1 championship?" when you don't know how to drive a car.

If I'm wrong, the Java Socket tutorials should give you everything you need: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/